# Firebase rule to not allow users to delete data from another users

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using firebase for a game, so I have this rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",
  "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["nickname", "attackPoints"],
      "$uid": {
        "nickname": {
          ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/)",
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "gold": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && newData.isNumber() && ((newData.val() >= 0 && newData.val() <= (data.val() + 1000)) || (data.exists() === false && newData.val() <= 1000))"
        },
        "experience": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && newData.isNumber() && ((newData.val() >= 0 && newData.val() <= (data.val() + 1000)) || (data.exists() === false && newData.val() <= 1000))"
        },
        "attackPoints": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && newData.isNumber() && ((newData.val() >= 0 && newData.val() <= (data.val() + 1000)) || (data.exists() === false && newData.val() <= 1000))"
        },
        "characterImageName": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "work": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "inventory": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
                "attacks": {
          "$attackId": {
            ".validate": "newData.child('attacker').val() === auth.uid || newData.child('target').val() === auth.uid || newData.child('target').val() === $uid",
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || data.child('attacker').val() === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || newData.child('attacker').val() === auth.uid || newData.child('target').val() === auth.uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I notice one user (userX) can delete all gold from any other user (userY...).

I tried to remove the `".write": "auth != null",` but it give permission deny when a new user try to register in the game

register code if needed:

```
 val nicknameRef = database.child("users").orderByChild("nickname").equalTo(nick)
nicknameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            // Username is already taken
            showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.username_is_already_taken))
        } else {
            // Username is available, proceed with registration
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this@Register) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val user = auth.currentUser
                        val userId = user?.uid

                        if (userId != null) {
                            val userData = HashMap<String, Any>()
                            userData["nickname"] = nick
                            userData["experience"] = 0
                            userData["gold"] = 200
                            userData["attackPoints"] = 35
                            userData["characterImageName"] = profile

                            database.child("users").child(userId).setValue(userData)
                                .addOnCompleteListener { dbTask ->
                                    if (dbTask.isSuccessful) {
                                        // Registration and data storage successful
                                        navigateToHome()
                                    } else {
                                        showErrorDialog(
                                            getString(
                                                R.string.error_while_saving_user_data_in_database,
                                                dbTask.exception?.message
                                            ))
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    } else {
                        showErrorDialog(
                            getString(
                                R.string.registration_error,
                                task.exception?.message
                            ))
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

How to avoid users to delete data from anothers users (like gold) and allow new users to register without permission deny error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and write permission in Firebase Realtime Database cascades down. This means that once you grant a user a permission on some level, you can't take that permission away on a lower level.

So with these rules you are essentially saying that everyone in the world can read the entire database, and anyone who is signed in can write the entire database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ...
```

No matter what read/write rules you have elsewhere in the rules, they can't override these top-level rules. For more on this, see [read and write rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade) in the docs.

---

So you will *have to* remove that top-level write rule if you don't want all users to be able to write everywhere in the database.

> I tried to remove the ".write": "auth != null", but it give permission deny when a new user try to register in the game

That means that you're now missing a rule that allows the write that you perform when a new user registers in the game. If that operation corresponds to this code:

```
database.child("users").child(userId).setValue(userData)
```

Then you'll need to actually grant the user write permission on that exact path. So:

```
"users": {
  ".indexOn": ["nickname", "attackPoints"],
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ...
```

So with this rule a user can write to the `/users/$uid` path, if the `userId` variable corresponds to their own UID (which it does in your code).

For more on this, also see the Firebase documentation on [securing content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#realtime-database_2).